# std::memory_order_relaxed atomicity with respect to the same atomic variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

The cppreference documentation about memory orders says

> Typical use for relaxed memory ordering is incrementing counters, such as the reference counters of std::shared_ptr, since this only requires atomicity, but not ordering or synchronization (**note that decrementing the shared_ptr counters requires acquire-release synchronization with the destructor**)

Does this mean that relaxed memory ordering don't actually result in atomicity with respect to the same variable?  But rather just results in eventual consistency with respect to other relaxed memory loads and/or `compare_exchange`s?  Using `std::memory_order_seq_cst` would be the only way to see consistent results when paired with `std::memory_order_relaxed`?

I was under the assumption that `std::memory_order_relaxed` is still atomic with respect to the same variable but does not provide any other constraints about loads and stores with respect to other data.

Comment: `std::memory_order_relaxed` guarantees atomicity, but no ordering or synchronization.  So it works for things like statistics counters, but can get tricky to use if the count is part of an invariant involving other memory locations.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison but then why would cppreference say that acquire-release is required?

Comment: Because memory needs to be in a synchronized state before it can be deleted. To explain why the increment can be `relaxed` while the decrement uses `acq/rel` is not trivial though

Comment: @LWimsey Do you mean that if the relaxed memory model is used there can be a read or write (if careful) to the reference counted state and that might get ordered after the delete operation in the destructor without stronger memory ordering?  That makes sense..  Also then why isn't consume-release used then?  Since the `delete` is a dependency off of the acquired value

Comment: Yes, that is what can theoretically happen. Maybe I'll post an answer with an example to explain `shared_ptr` memory ordering.(or at least an attempt).

Comment: @Curious You already got an answer, so I'll just write a short comment ;). The phrase "don't actually result in atomicity" makes me think you confuse atomicity with memory order. Atomicity just means that it is safe to do concurrent access by different threads without causing Undefine Behavior in the form of a data race. You still don't know which thread was first, but the program is still well defined. Ordering is way more complex, as it is about the order in different threads see side effects of atomic operations (writes). But for any given (atomic) variable, all threads will always see the

Comment: same order, no matter what memory ordering you use (e.g. relaxed). This has to be the case, since if you write 1, then 2 and then 3 to a variable x, the last value written is the one that sticks when enough time did pass. You can see this order as being defined by the order in which writes arrive at the final destination in memory, of which there is only one (the caches (L1, L2, L3..) make this more complex in reality but you can not observe that other than accessing a variable from one thread is fast (cached) while accessing the same variable from multiple threads concurrently is slow.)

Comment: @Curious "_isn't consume-release used_" `delete` is consuming... what?

Comment: @LWimsey "_To explain why the increment can be relaxed while the decrement uses acq/rel is not trivial though_" Simply put nothing important happens when a RC reaches an high point (and there is no maximum value anyway) and something very important happens when it reaches a low point (RC > 0 by definition). So increasing and decreasing operations are fundamentally dissimilar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are asking a few things, but I'll focus on the ordering constraints used by a typical `shared_ptr` implementation because I think that covers the key part of your question.

An atomic operation is *always* atomic with respect to the variable (or POD) it applies to; modifications to a single variable *will* become visible to all threads in a consistent order.
The way relaxed atomic operations work is described in your question:

> `std::memory_order_relaxed` is still atomic with respect to the same variable but does not provide any other constraints about loads and stores with respect to other data

The following are 2 typical scenario's whereby ordering constraints on an atomic operation can be omitted (i.e. by using `std::memory_order_relaxed`):

1. Memory ordering is not necessary because there are no dependencies on other operations, or as a commenter puts it, (..) is not part of an invariant involving other memory locations.

   A common example is an atomic counter, incremented by multiple threads to keep track of the number of times a particular event has occurred.
   The increment operation (`fetch_add`) can be relaxed if the counter represents a value that has no dependency on other operations.
   I find the example given by cppreference not very convincing because the `shared_ptr` reference count *does* have a dependency; i.e. memory is deleted once its value becomes zero.
   A better example is a web server keeping track of the number of incoming requests only for reporting purposes.
2. Memory ordering is necessary, but there is no *need* to use ordering constraints because the required synchronization has already passed
   (IMO this explains better why `shared_ptr`'s reference count increment can be relaxed, see example below).
   The `shared_ptr` copy/move constructor can only be called while it has a synchronized view of the (reference to the) copied/moved-from instance (or it would be undefined behavior)
   and as such, no additional ordering is necessary.

The following example illustrates how memory ordering is typically used by a `shared_ptr` implementation to modify its reference count. Assume that all threads run in parallel
*after* `sp_main` has been released (the `shared_ptr` reference count is then 10).

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    auto sp_main = std::make_shared<int>(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        // sp_main is passed by value
        v.push_back(thread{thread_func, sp_main, i});
    }

    sp_main.reset();

    for (auto &t : v)  t.join();
}

void thread_func(std::shared_ptr<int> sp, int n)
{
    // 10 threads are created

    if (n == 7)
    {
        // Only thread #7 modifies the integer
        *sp = 42;
    }

    // The only thead with a synchronized view of the managed integer is #7
    // All other threads cannot read/write access the integer without causing a race

    // 'sp' going out of scope -> destructor called
}
```

Thread creation guarantees an (inter-thread) happens-before relationship between `make_shared` (in `main`) and `sp`'s copy/move-constructor (inside each thread).
Therefore, `shared_ptr`'s constructor has a synchronized view of memory and can safely increment `ref_count` with no additional ordering:

```
ctrlblk->ref_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

For the destruction part, since only thread `#7` writes to the shared integer, the others 9 threads are not allowed to access the same memory location without causing a race.
This creates a problem because all threads are destructed at about the same time (assume `reset` in `main` has been called earlier)
and only one thread is going to delete the shared integer (the one decrementing `ref_count` from 1 to 0).
It is imperative that the last thread has a synchronized memory view before it deletes the integer, but since 9 out of 10 threads do not have a synchronized view, additional ordering is necessary.

The destructor may contain something like:

```
if (ctrlblk->ref_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1)
{
    // delete managed memory
}
```

The atomic `ref_count` has a single modification order and therefore all atomic modifications occur in some order.
Let's say the threads (in this example) that perform the last 3 decrements on `ref_count` are thread `#7` (3 → 2), `#5` (2 → 1) and `#3` (1 → 0).
Both decrements performed by threads `#7` and `#5` come earlier in the modification order than the one performed by `#3`.
The release sequence becomes:

> `#7` (store release) → `#5` (read-modify-write, no ordering required) → `#3` (load acquire)

The end result is that the release operation performed by thread `#7` has synchronized with the acquire operation performed by `#3` and the integer modification (by `#7`) is guaranteed to have
happened before the integer destruction (by `#3`).

Technically, only the threads that have accessed the managed memory location have to perform a release operation, but since a library implementer does not know about thread actions,
all threads perform a release operation upon destruction.

For the final destruction of shared memory, technically only the last thread needs to perform an acquire operation and therefore a `shared_ptr` library implementer could optimize by setting a standalone fence
that is only called by the last thread.

```
if (ctrlblk->ref_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1)
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

    // delete managed memory
}
```

Comment: I do not see why `std::memory_order_relaxed` cannot be used for decrementing the reference counter since there are no other loads/stores that must not be reordered with respect to the atomic change of the reference counter.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  The store to the shared integer (42 in the example) must be released by the modifying thread (#7) and acquired by the last thread (#3). Without that ordering, deleting the shared memory location constitutes a data race.

Comment: "_because the shared_ptr reference count does have a dependency_" but reading the refcount in a MT program is considered unreliable. You shouldn't need to `use_count()>X`; the only relevant event for a refcount is when it **goes down** to zero.

Comment: "_The only thead[sic] with a synchronized view of the managed integer is #7_" Your program is perfectly legal and must be supported by `std::shared_ptr` so it's technically a valid example that proves your point; OTOH it's an exceptionally inane design: all threads but one receive an object they cannot do anything with except to safely destroy it. Perfect for language lawyer land, bad for a learning course.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The posted code is 100% legal but highly unrealistic. In practice an object shared by different threads with no internal synchronization is going to be used as a read only object. All threads will read the object and when they are done, they decrement the counter. This needs to happen in that order; OTOH the increment of the counter need not happen immediately, it's weakly ordered (it only needs to happen before the decrement).

Comment: If a function makes a copy and destroys it, without any synchronization in between, or anything that acts on any `shared_ptr`, both operations can be omitted: `void f(shared_ptr<T> x) { if (x->foo()) g(move(x)); }` By inlining `f` the compiler could potentially completely avoid the refcount manipulation of the condition is false and push it later in inlined `g` if it's true.

Comment: But the acquire-operation in the last thread (#3) will not see the release-operation of thread #7, only the release-operation of thread #5. The result of this that the release-operation of #5 will be synchronized-with the acquire-operation of thread #3, and the memory accesses of thread #7 will not be synchronized with the last thread. So how is the logic in the answer is correct?

Comment: @plasmacel The key word is 'release sequence'. The C++ standard states that in a valid release sequence, the value stored by thread A may be modified by other threads B, C, D, etc.. until the last thread Z acquires the then-current value.
Ordering requirements only apply to A (release) and Z (acquire). For threads B,C,D,..,Y, no specific ordering requirements exist, only that the value is changed by an atomic read-modify-write operation.
If those requirements are met, the store/release in A synchronizes with the load/acquire in Z.

Comment: @LWimsey Yes, but there is no guarantee here that thread #7 will be the first member of the release sequence. What if an another thread, say thread #9 runs the same piece of code before #7? Then the release-operation of thread #9 will be the first member of the release sequence, which will synchronize-with the last member (the acquire-operation in thread #3). In this case there is no happens-before relation between #7 and #3, and the memory access in thread #7 won't be synchronized with the delete in thread #3.

Comment: @plasmacel All threads run in an unspecified order. In the example, the decrement in thread #9 came before #7 (since 7,5,3 performed the last 3 decrements),
but that does not matter since #9 did not modify the integer and thus has nothing to release.
The release sequence is headed by the store/release that is performed by the modifying thread and in this case that is the release operation in thread #7.

Comment: @LWimsey The definition of release sequence says otherwise. "After a release operation A is performed on an atomic object M, the longest continuous subsequence of the modification order of M that consists of atomic read-modify-write operations made to M by any thread is known as release sequence headed by A" In the example the first release operation performed on the atomic variable is the `fetch_sub` of thread #9, so the release sequence is headed by that, regardless how you modify or not modify other variables, thus #3 doesn't synchronize with #7.

Comment: @plasmacel In this context, the standard uses 'release operation' wrt the store/release that actually releases the updated value (#7). Thread #9 does not do that since it did not modify anything. But the way they have phrased it may indeed leave some room for confusion.

Comment: @plasmacel Why don't you post a new question about this? There are others who can explain it better than me

Comment: @LWimsey I think I will, besides other questions. My impression is that everyone has a different interpretation of acquire-release semantics. I read a lot of resources including Jeff Preshings's series on the topic and the book C++ Concurrency In Action, and also the standard. Still, even the standard makes paradoxical statements and has holes, besides that it doesn't explain anything. I really don't understand anyway how the acquire on an another thread will know which one is the "real" release which actually releases value(s) without possibly confusing it with other written values.

Comment: @plasmacel In the example, there cannot be other threads that modify/release a written value since that would be a datarace on the managed integer and thus undefined behavior.