# std::shared_ptr copy constructor thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

std::shared_ptr specification guarentees that only one thread will invoke delete on the internal pointer.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124031/stdmemory-order-relaxed-atomicity-with-respect-to-the-same-atomic-variable) has a really nice explanation about the required memory ordering on the shared_ptr refrence count manipulation in order to guarentee that the delete will be invoked on a synchronized memory.

What I don't understand is the following:

- If a shared_ptr is initialized by a copy constructor, is it
  guarenteed that it will either be empty or a valid shared_ptr?

I am looking at MVCC implementation of shared_ptr copy constructor. and I think I can identify at least one race condition.

```
template<class _Ty2>
    void _Copy_construct_from(const shared_ptr<_Ty2>& _Other)
    {   // implement shared_ptr's (converting) copy ctor
    if (_Other._Rep)
        {
        _Other._Rep->_Incref();
        }

    _Ptr = _Other._Ptr;
    _Rep = _Other._Rep;
    }
```

The implementation checks that the control block is valid, then incerement its reference count, and copy assigns the internal fields.

Assuming `_Other` is owned by a different thread then the one calling the copy constructor. If between the lines `if (_Other._Rep)` and `_Other._Rep->_Incref();` this thread calls the destructor that happens to delete the control block and the pointer, then `_Other._Rep->_Incref()` will dereference a deleted pointer.

### Further Clarification

Here is a code that illustrates the corner case I am talking about.
I will tweak share_ptr copy constructor implementation to simulate a context switch:

```
template<class _Ty2>
    void _Copy_construct_from(const shared_ptr<_Ty2>& _Other)
    {   // implement shared_ptr's (converting) copy ctor
    if (_Other._Rep)
        {
        // now lets put here a really long loop or sleep to simulate a context switch
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; ++i)
        {           
            for (int j = 0; j < 99999999; ++j)
            {
              count++;
           }
        }

        // by the time we get here, the owning thread may already destroy the  shared_ptr that was passed to this constructor
        _Other._Rep->_Incref();
        }

    _Ptr = _Other._Ptr;
    _Rep = _Other._Rep;
    }
```

And here is a code that will probably show the problem:

```
int main()
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> sh1 = std::make_shared<int>(123);
        auto lambda = [&]()
        {
            auto sh2 = sh1;
            std::cout << sh2.use_count(); // this prints garbage, -572662306 in my case
        };

        std::thread t1(lambda);
        t1.detach();
        // main thread destroys the shared_ptr
        // background thread probably did not yet finished executing the copy constructor
    }



    Sleep(10000);

}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that an object can be copied in one thread while the same object is being destroyed in another?

Comment: By that measure, a mutex isn't "thread safe" either...

Comment: "_now lets put here a really long loop or sleep to simulate a context switch_"
        `int count = 0;` make it `volatile`: the compiler is only expected to produce the same **observable** behavior of the program, that is the same interactions with the external world as those of an execution of the virtual machine as described by the C++ specification. **An empty loop has no observable behavior at all, it can be removed.** An access to a `volatile` qualified object by definition is an observable and thus a loop accessing such object cannot be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulation of the state shared by `shared_ptr` objects is thread-safe; `shared_ptr` *itself* is not thread-safe. You cannot manipulate the same `shared_ptr` object from different threads at the same time; attempting to do so is a data race and thus UB.

So your code would be fine if `lambda` copied the pointer before being shipped off to another thread.

It should also be noted that your specific example could *never* work, no matter how `shared_ptr` was written. The type could be `atomic<int>` and it would still be just as broken. You gave the lambda a reference to an object that may not exist before the lambda gets to execute the copy operation.

No amount of internal thread-safety can save you there. Passing a reference to a stack variable to another thread should always be looked on as a code smell.

Answer (score 4):

When `shared_ptr` is used *properly*, what your describe can never happen.

The `shared_ptr` that is being copied from has incremented the refcount before being passed to the copy constructor, and it can't be destructed until after the copy constructor has exited since it is a local parameter of the constructor.

Thus, another thread will not destroy the object that is being shared. The refcount of `_Other.Rep` will always be at least 1 upon entry into the copy constructor if `_Other.Rep` is not null.

**UPDATE**: your use case is faulty. The lambda captures a *reference* to the main thread's `shared_ptr` instance but the thread does not make a copy of that `shared_ptr` until after it has already gone out of scope and been destroyed by `main`. Your thread has a **dangling reference** causing your code to have **undefined behavior**. That is not a fault of the `shared_ptr` implementation. Your lambda needs to capture the `shared_ptr` **by value** instead of **by reference** instead, so its refcount is incremented immediately, before the thread is created, not when the thread starts running.

Comment: What do you mean by used properly? I know that the ref count is incremented before the actual copy, what I claim is that a decrement can come just before that increment. I will later edit my post with an example to better illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @NinaKaprez you are missing the point. The `_Other` parameter passed into the copy constructor has its own reference to the shared object, so its refcount is already at least 1 going into the constructor, and will then be incremented by the constructor. It doesn't matter if other `shared_ptr`s reference the same shared object, (in|de)crementing its refcount while the constructor is running. The refcount will remain at least 1, even if all the other references are cleared, the constructor will still have an active reference in the `_Other` parameter until after the constructor exits.

Comment: @NinaKaprez The shared object will not be deleted until ALL references have been cleared and its refcount falls to 0. And by *properly*, I mean not doing something stupid like accessing a raw pointer to the shared object directly and deleting it manually, or mishandling it by assigning it to multiple owning smart pointers, etc.

Comment: I think I understood your point. Yet I am talking about a corner case where the shared_ptr copy constructor is invoked by a non-owning thread. I edited my question to include an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Look at his example; the lambda captures the stack object *by reference*; it won't copy that object until it gets executed in the other thread. The two threads are in a race to manipulate the same `shared_ptr` object, not copies that refer to the same shared state.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, I came to the same conclusion after seeing the OP's update and before seeing your comment