# Is counter in std::shared_ptr atomic?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, atomic

At the interview, I was asked what is the peculiarity of the counter in `std::shared_ptr`(it is an atomic). However, I have heard opinions that `std::shared_ptr` doesn't work well with multithreading. What is true?

Comment: Yes, it has an atomic counter. Saying that it "doesn't work well with multithreading" is really vague, though. That all depends on what you do with it and what your metrics for good or bad are.

Comment: There are other ways to implement a shared_ptr that don't require a counter (use a ring of pointers between the shared_ptrs).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124031/stdmemory-order-relaxed-atomicity-with-respect-to-the-same-atomic-variable/48148318#48148318) has more details about the atomic counter in `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

In other words, you can construct and copy them safely but the shared object itself is not protected.

Comment: Where'd the quote come from?

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's from the Cpp Reference documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr .

Comment: Thanks.  Cppreference.com isn't definitive, but it is usually very good.