# C++ std::shared_ptr custom deleter thread safety

Tags: c++, c++17

[edited with a more concrete example]

Suppose I have a thread-safe object (all public member use a mutex) and a shared_ptr with a custom deleter, like so:

```
class A {
public:
  void update(int x);
  void print_sum();
  ...
}

class AContainer {
    private SomeConcurrentMap<string, shared_ptr<A>> aMap;
    void newA(string name) {
        aMap.emplace(name, shared_ptr<A>(new A, [](A *p){p->print_sum(); delete p;}));
    }
    void finalizeA(string name) {
        aMap.erase(name);
    }
    shared_ptr<A> getA(string name) const {
        // fixme handle case of not found...
        return aMap.find(name).second;
    }
};

void someFunctionInSomeThread(const AContainer &cont, string name, int c) {
    // fixme handle case of not found...
    cont.getA(name)->update(c);
}
```

Let's assume all A operation are protected by a mutex, and that SomeConcurrentMap is thread-safe. The usage is scenario is:

1. call `AContainer::newA()` from any thread
2. call `someFunctionInSomeThread()` multiple times by multiple threads
3. call `AContainer::finalizeA()` from any thread - possibly in parallel to step 2

And the idea that A::print_sum() is called after both step 3 completed and all running A::update() operations complete.

Is it safe to assume that by the time `p->print_sum()` is called, all the `A::update()` operations on the object have been called?

Comment: Yes, this is safe, regardless of whether your object is otherwise thread-safe or not. Otherwise `shared_ptr` would be very hard to use from several threads.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` code calls the deleter when the **last** `shared_ptr` object that manages that pointer is being destroyed. Since there is only one `shared_ptr` object, there is no possibility of multiple threads accessing the same object (absent truly perverse code, i.e., passing the address of the `shared_ptr` object to another thread).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat usually the wizdom around shared_ptr and thread safety is that shared_ptr guarantees only the safety of the control block. Do you mean that it's safe regardless of whether the object is thread safe because deleter is a special case somehow? Perhaps update() must be thread-safe and print_sum() doesn't have to be?

Comment: Your description sounds safe, but an MRE so we can confirm the code with our own eyes would help to get a guaranteed answer.

Comment: @UriSimchoni Are you using the same `std::shared_ptr` object in different threads, ie have you shared a shared_ptr ? If so there will be race-conditions.  Using 2 different shared_ptr controlling the same object in different threads is safe.  Please include a [mcve] to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: You might want to read [the explanation why decrementing `shared_ptr` ref counters requires `std::memory_order_acquire/release`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48124031/2752075). What I meant is that it's safe for one thread to call a function on a shared object, then kill its pointer, then for the other thread to kill the last pointer and call the deleter, regardless of thread-safety of that function or the deleter.

Comment: By definition, since you postulate that "reference count reaches zero", no thread has a pointer to `A` instance anymore on which to call `update` in parallel with `print_sum`. Unless there's a bug in the code not shown and someone calls `update` through a dangling pointer - then it's undefined behavior, threads or no threads.

Comment: As long as you don't extract the pointer from the shared_ptr and let it expire prematurely it will be safe. Make sure not do do so accidentally, e.g. when the shared_ptr is returned as a temporary and used to call update without giving it a name.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to assume that by the time p->print_sum() is called, all the A::update() operations on the object have been called?

Yes, it is safe to assume that.  Only one thread is going to call the destructor, and no thread is going to call the destructor before calling other member functions of `A` (such a thread would be invoking UB even if no other threads existed, e.g. by keeping a raw pointer after destroying the shared pointer and then accessing the object via the raw pointer).

Comment: The implicit assumption in this answer is that the different threads each have their own copy of the `shared_ptr`. If that is not the case, and the threads access a single `shared_ptr`, then UB is possible.